# Search in the related model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have post table like this :

```
id | post_title | category_id
```

and this is category table

```
id | category_title
```

this is the relation between these two which is inside post model :

```
  public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }
```

I want to get the record of post table where category_title or post_title matches the keyword entered by user.

I'm retrieving data something like:

```
Post::where(['title'=>$request->title])->with('category')->paginate(10);
```

but here it is only fetching Post title but i also want it to search it in category title.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Post::where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->title.'%')->with(['category' => function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('category_title', 'like', '%'.$request->title.'%');
    }])->paginate(10);
```

In the above code snippet

1. We are fetching the title which matches with the request
2. `with(['category' => function($query) use ($request)`: laravel matches the result into relationship using closure function which accepts one parameter `$request`
   and again we are filtering the relationship with this parameter $request->title which is coming through `Request $request`

You can use the code above or you can make a scope for reusability.

Answer (score 0):

```
Post::->where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->title.'%')->with(['category' => function($query) use ($request){
    $query->where('category_title', 'like', '%'.$request->title.'%');
}])->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$keyword = $request->input('title');

Post::with('category')
     ->where('title', 'like','%'.$keyword.'%')
     ->orWhere('category.category_title','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
     ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [orWhereHas](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_orWhereHas):

```
 Post::where(['title' => $request->title])->
        orWhereHas('category',function ($query)use($request){
            $query->where('category_title',$request->title);
        })->with('category')-> paginate(10);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: an answer without 'what and how' is incomplete answer, but it is not a bad one